# PhoneJs not working for Windows Phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, phonejs

I have developed an app using **PhoneJs** framework for all mobile plateforms like Android, iOs, BleckBerry and Windows Phone. Now I came to know that **PhoneJs** doesn't support Windows Phone 7. I have to launch my app in next two days everything is ready except WP7. Can anyone suggest me some alternates for WP7 using **PhoneJs**. or how can I do porting for WP7.

Answer (score 1):

While Windows Phone 7.x platform is not officially supported by PhoneJS, most apps will work, with partially degraded UI and performance. For example, I just checked the [TipCalculator demo](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Demos/?url=TipCalculator) on HTC Mozart browser.

Packaging for WP7 can be done with [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/).